# Responsive DIV to fill entire screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to format an HTML DIV element so that it is responsive on mobile devices. My goal is to have the dive always fill the 100% of the width and height of any mobile device whether it is a ipad, iphone or androd device. I.E. different size screens.

I cannot get this code to do that however. Where and I going wrong?

My DIV Element:

```
<!---Main Responsive DIV --->
    <div class="fullscreen" id="fullscreen">

    <!--- This is where we draw. --->
    <div align="center" style="vertical-align:middle">
    <canvas
    id="canvas"
    width="400"
    height="250"
    style="border:3px dashed #000000;">
    </canvas>
    </div>

      <!---
    This is the form that will post the drawing information
    back to the server.
    --->
      <cfoutput>
        <form action="signature_action.cfm?ticketID=#url.ticketID#&TT=#url.TT#&techID=#url.techID#&device=ipad" method="post">

          <!--- The canvas dimensions. --->
          <input type="hidden" name="width" value="1000" />
          <input type="hidden" name="height" value="615" />

          <!--- The drawing commands. --->
          <input type="hidden" name="commands" value="" />
          <!--- This is the export feature. --->

          <!--- Navigation Elements --->
          <div id="footer">
          <A HREF="javascript:history.back()">Go back</A><a href="">Capture Signature</a>
          </div>

        </form>
      </cfoutput>
      </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#fullscreen {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background: pink;
        @

    }
    @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw; }

    @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw; }

    #footer {
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
       width:100%;
       height:110px;   /* Height of the footer */
       background:#6cf;
    }

    table
    {
       border-collapse:collapse;

    }
    table.borderAll
    {
       border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }
    tr.bottomMedium
    {
       border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }
    tr.bottomThin
    {
       border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    }
    tr.bottomDouble
    {
       border-bottom: 2px double #000;
    }
    tr.last
    {
       border-bottom: none;
    }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use sizing with CSS3's `vw` and `vh` [units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/)

```
   #fullscreen {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

def:

```
100vw = 100% of viewport width
100vh = 100% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```

Update:

```
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw; }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw; }
```

Comment: Will that automatically resize if a tablet user goes from portrait to landscape mode?

Comment: For instance on an iPhone, it looks correct in portrait mode, but when I switch to lanscape, it doesn't automatically adjust to fill the 100% of the viewport. Can that only be done with javascript?

Comment: @Brian Fleishman it shall work but try to add the update that will fixe it if not and what browser are you using on the iphone? is it supported in caniuse?

Comment: I am using the Safari browser in iOS8. Should your CSS update be added as additional CSS items?

Comment: I edited my post with my latest updates as well as my full HTML code for my page. Seems to work on my iPad (iOS8) but not my iPhone (iOS8).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61917/discussion-between-tambo-and-brian-fleishman).

Answer (score 1):

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

This assumes that you want the div to scroll when overflowed. Should work on any device, unlike `vh` and `vw` that have partial support for a few browsers

Answer (score 0):

You have to give to the body and html also the height of 100%;

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```